# Edit & Remove items in a check list box using buttons

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, checklistbox

I have a button that adds items to a check list box.

```
private void btnDelivery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deliveryForm.deliverytrips = new DeliveryTrips();
    deliveryForm.ShowDialog();
    if (deliveryForm.deliverytrips != null)
    {
        DeliveryTrips newApp = deliveryForm.deliverytrips;
        theDelivery.addDeliveryTrip(newApp);
    }
    updateList();
}

private void updateList()
{
    clbSummary.Items.Clear();
    List<String> listOfDelivery = theDelivery.listDeliveryTrips();
    clbSummary.Items.AddRange(listOfDelivery.ToArray());
}
```

Using buttons how could I edit, What I have added to the checklist box or delete it from the check list box?

just now i have this for editing a item

```
        int index = clbSummary.SelectedIndex;



        DeliveryTrips selected = theDelivery.getDeliveryTrips(index);


        deliveryForm.deliverytrips = selected;



        deliveryForm.ShowDialog();


        updateList();
```

but that only edits the items if selected and not checked, same with the remove button, it only removes the item if selected and not checked .

Thanks

Comment: The problem with your method is that you effectively have two ways to indicate selection in a `CheckedListBox`: selection and checking. I would be inclined to change the control to a regular `ListBox`, or decide on one way of detecting selection and stick with that.

Comment: The CheckedListBox has a CheckedItems enumeration.

Comment: SidHolland would rather keep the [tag:CheckedListBox] as it is a summary of all the items that i will be adding to the [tag:CheckedListBox]besucse later i will be moving certain items to a [tag:ListBox] so it should hopefully be easier to move a few checked items to a different [tag:ListBox] instead of move one selected item to a different [tag:ListBox]

@LarsTech i have tried using the CheckedItems but i get a req line under it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete is the easy part. If your list supports a single item selected (`SelectionMode` `One`), you can do something like

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    clbSummary.Items.RemoveAt(clbSummary.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Now, if you support multiple selection (`SelectionMode` `MultiSimple`/`MultiExtended` - Works for standard lists, not CheckboxLists), the following code will remove the entire selection

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = clbSummary.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        clbSummary.Items.RemoveAt(clbSummary.SelectedIndices[i]);
    }
}
```

Here, it is very important to reverse the order, otherwise the removal in items will shift the content of your `clbSummary` and the more you delete items, the bigger the offset will be.

If you want to remove the Checked items, it's the same thing, but you use `CheckedIndices`

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = clbSummary.CheckedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        clbSummary.Items.RemoveAt(clbSummary.CheckedIndices[i]);
    }
}
```

To edit, I would suggest creating a form to edit the content of your item, or if it's only a string, maybe a simple input dialog would be sufficient (I really simplified it using a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to use an `InputBox`). Usually your items might correspond to more complex objects than strings so a proper `Editor` might be necessary (a Form made specifically to edit your items)

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string content = clbSummary.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string newValue = Interaction.InputBox("Provide new value", "New Value", content, -1, -1);
    int selectedIndex = clbSummary.SelectedIndex;
    clbSummary.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    clbSummary.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, newValue);
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks
i already have a forum to use that lets me add and edit items then updates them.
only have one problem left now, its working if have a item selected, i just need to change it so instead of the selected item it does it to the checked item

i tried to use `Int index = clbSummary.CheckedItems;` but i just get a red line under the code, perhaps I'm missing something out?

Comment: `CheckedItems` is a `Collection`, it contains many items. You will have to select one out of this `Collection`, so for editing I would suggest going with `SelectionMode` `One`, and edit the `SelectedItem`